# What is the difference between samba and sssd?

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba, sssd

In my ubuntu workstation I use `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` with `/etc/krb5.conf` in order to join active directory on a corporate network.

```sh
sudo service samba-ad-dc status
# inactive

sudo service sssd status
# active (running)
```

However I cannot yet tell what is the difference between samba and sssd. 
Can someone explain what are the differences between these two services and where do they overlap?

- Can sssd work even without samba. Does it directly read `smb.conf`?
- How do they depend to each other?

I have read the documentation, but I need a simpler explanation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. You might be better off asking at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: But I think the answer to your question is that SSSD is used for the authentication, while SMB is the actual protocol for reading/writing the files. This article might help: [Using SMB Shares with SSSD and Winbind](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/smb-sssd)

Comment: @GabrielLuci The answer implies that `SMB==samba`. Because I asked about samba.

Comment: Question migrated to: https://serverfault.com/questions/996681/what-is-the-difference-between-samba-and-sssd

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you are trying to log in your workstation using the domain credentials. For that, you do not need samba. You just need set up the sssd.

I don't know which packages are necessary in an ubuntu box, but the packages needed for a Red Hat Enterprise Linux based are these:

> realmd samba-common-tools krb5-workstation oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir
> adcli

To join in the domain the command is this one:

> realm join --user=user_with_permission_to_add_computers_in_the_domain --computer-ou=OU="OU_to_add" domain_name.com

The configuration file, as you mentioned, is this:

> /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

I find useful to add this options in the configuration file:

- **access_provider** = simple # This will allow you to control who can log
  in the computer using the simple_allow_groups below.
- **use_fully_qualified_names** = False # Allow you to log on using just
  the username, not the standard option username@domainname
- **fallback_homedir** = /home/%d/%u # Change the home directory to /home/domainname/username
- **simple_allow_groups** = groupname1, groupname2 # Domain groupnames allow you to limit the log on permission for just the members of the groups in this option.

To enable the service:

```
systemctl enable sssd
systemctl start sssd
```

**Some useful commands**:

To clear the cache:

```
sss_cache -E
```

To check if the workstation is member of a domain:

```
realm list
```

To check the status of the domain:

```
sssctl domain-status domainname
```

To leave the domain:

```
realm leave -U user_with_permission_to_add_computers_in_the_domain domainname
```

I hope you find this explanation useful.